# Tumblr Custom Layout under header

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am working on a project for a client of ours and customising a page on tumblr is part of it where I am having a bit of a struggle on how to approach the issue.

Basically what we have is a tumblr page and a theme however this theme is not allowed to be changed and adjustments are not be made either.

We need to create a new separate page to the existing tumblr website that keeps the header and navigation menu of the blog but everything else beneath it has to follow different CSS than what the theme offers. Example, the post-container div needs to be 100% width of the browser size which the current theme won't do.

I can't show the page itself due to confidentiality reasons but here is a sample! http://justfowo.tumblr.com/test

Any help on how to tackle this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sadly your question is too broad. A good question should show what you have tried and a specific problem. I would also question why you aren't allowed to modify the existing theme?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your broad question, I can give a hint that might help you (as it seems that you don't have experience with Tumblr CMS):

- Create a static page with a custom theme inside the existent tumblr (you can copy your main tumblr theme to here and adapt it).

[image: Create a static page with a custom theme inside the existent tumblr]

Comment: I think actually it would be better to use the Standard layout and then add a wrapper to that page and insert custom html. That way the header and footer will still get inherited, but it is then possible to write css for that page/section.